# WPF image zooming

Tags: wpf, zooming, out

WPF: What is the best way to implement Zoom In and Zoom Out option for an Image inside ScrollViewer in WPF at runtime and also other alternative methods for the same

Please provide sample code and suggest links where I can find sample code and more info about various ways to Zoom the image.

Regards,
Anwar

Answer (score 0):

There are many pan and zoom viewers for wpf.  A few that I have found helpful to learn and to borrow code are:

WPF Extensions
http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/

Pan and Zoom (DeepZoom style) in WPF 
http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2008/08/05/pan-and-zoom-deepzoom-style-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ScaleTransform` to zoom in and out, and a `TranslateTransform` for panning